# How to programmatically import a block to existing view?

Tags: 7, views, importing-exporting

I need to programmatically **import a block to existing view with its settings**.

[image]

**I know how to export the whole view and import it programmatically.** But I don't want to export whole view and then import whole view. In my view there is 25 blocks, so it gives me 4000 lines of code to import.
I can copy export code only of my new block. But **how to import only this part of code to the existing view**? Is that possible? I can't find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indicated "block" you point out in the UI, is internally called a "display". Displays are stored inside the view object in the `display` property (e.g. `$view->display`).

If you look at the views export code you should see the pattern of exported blocks (e.g. `/* Display: Block 1 */`, `/* Display: Block 2 */`, etc.) that's rendered by the [`views::export()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views/-/blob/afb6d5c870add8d46b6b05300482df10f1aef8f7/includes/view.inc#L1959) method.

For each block (i.e. display) you should see the `$handler = $view->new_display(...)` followed by many `$handler->display...` lines that add the relevant fields/filters for that display.

To programmatically import a single display you would do something like the following:

```
$view = views_get_view('my_existing_view');
// @TODO: Add my new display handler code
$view->save();
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm :)